# Desktop wallpaper goes Black when Nautilus is opened in xfce

Tags: nautilus, xfce, desktop-background

I had xfce desktop installed. I use nautilus for instead of thunar for sharing purpose.when I just came across a weird issue. I was using nautilus normaly some time ago but after some time when I opened the nautilus the screen wallpaper goes black.It only happens to nautilus. Thunar works just fine.When I use `xkill` and click on Desktop nautilus closes and wallpaper goes to normal

[image]

[image]

here is output of nautilus command in termianl:-

```
$ nautilus

(nautilus:7084): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (nautilus:7084): CRITICAL **: Another desktop manager in use; desktop window won't be created
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had installed `mint-artwork-cinnamon` package from mint repos. I removed it and then everything works fine again.